# My HTML5 video tag is not playing the video

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video

Im trying to play a video uploaded by the user using the `<video` tag but it doesnt seem to be loading to the DOM for some reason. Here is my code:

```
function Videos ({uploadedFiles}){

    if (uploadedFiles) {
            console.log(uploadedFiles[0])
            return(
                <div>
                    <h3>Videos</h3>

                        <video controls width="400">
                            <source src={uploadedFiles[0]} type="video/mp4"/>
                            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                        </video>

                </div>
            )
    } else return(<div> <h2> No Video Uploaded </h2></div>)
}
```

When i  do `console.log(uploadedFiles[0])` i get `y2mate.com - after_effect_countdown_10_seconds_iDO9J_3OVJ0_1080p.mp4` which should work inside the video tag as the `src`. My doctype is html. Any ideas where im going wrong?

Comment: Do you mean "autoplay" without user gesture? Have you tried with `<video autoplay muted ...>`?

Comment: @devserkan no. It just doesnt play at all. The video doesnt even load

Comment: Do you see the right source name in the DOM tree? Have you tried it without spaces in the source name?

Comment: @devserkan when i do `console.log(document.getElementById('video')` after changing the `<source>` id to video, i get null

Comment: What do you see when you look with developer tools? Do you mean the video tag is getting null after you set the source?

Comment: @devserkan no the source tag returns null after i set it

Comment: If it is getting null then something is going weird. If upload is succesfull and you are setting it correctly then at least it should be loaded. Maybe something about the path?

Comment: if you look in the networks panel, can you see the request status of the video? did the request fail?

Comment: Is your uploaded files client file to be uploaded or uploaded server files.

Comment: have you tried with quotes around the `"{uploadedFiles[0]}"`, also, if it's returning `y2mate.com - after_effect_countdown_10_seconds_iDO9J_3OVJ0_1080p.mp4` that's not a valid path

Comment: @Olian04 the request is successful

Comment: @KrisRoofe they are client files to be uploaded

Comment: @Offbeatmammal ive changed the file name to simply `video.mp4` and its still not working. Also tried the quote marks but hasn't worked

Comment: @SeanBarker see if my Answer helps you to get video playback.

Comment: can you echo the entire response to the console, and then check if the path shown in the video source is what you expect

Answer (score 0):

> *"I'm trying to play a video uploaded by the user using the `<video>` tag but it doesn' seem to be loading to the DOM for some reason"*

Try the way shown below and see if it works better. If successful, then apply a similar logic to your code. This means using a **blob** instead of a `src={uploadedFiles[0]}`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p> Choose A Video File... </p>
<input type="file" id="fileChooser" accept="*/*"/>

<div>
<a id="aTag"> </a>
</div>

<script>

document.getElementById('fileChooser').addEventListener('change', onFileSelected, false);

function onFileSelected(evt) 
{
    var file = evt.target.files[0]; // FileList object
    var type = file.type;

    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    var tmpElement; //# represents new video tag element....
    var path; //will hold URL of file BLOB (not file path)....

    reader.onloadend = function(evt) 
    {

        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) 
        {
            //# update file path...
            path = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);

            //# remove any other existing media element...
            var container = document.getElementById("aTag");
            container.removeChild(container.childNodes[0]); 

            tmpElement = document.createElement( "video");
            tmpElement.setAttribute("controls", "true" );
            tmpElement.setAttribute("width", "800");

            //# add newly created HTML5 element with file path
            tmpElement.setAttribute("src", path);
            container.appendChild(tmpElement);
        }
    };

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```