# Why is the html video tag not loading my video?

Tags: javascript, html, video

Im trying to play a video uploaded by the user using the

```
function HomePage (){

    return(
        <div>
            <h3>Home</h3>
            <div>

                    <video autoplay width= "300">
                            <source src="hi.mp4" id='video' type="video/mp4"/>
                            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                    </video>

                </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I've uploaded `hi.mp4` to the same folder as `HomePage.js`. I was having issues with a more complicated code than this but simplified it signficantly to see if it would work, but im still having issues with it. Does anyone know why this isnt working? Am i misunderstanding how to use the `src` attribute?

Comment: Does it work locally when you try it? Try appending a ```/``` before the src of the video

Comment: could be a number of reasons why the video might not show...have you tried using your browser's Developer Tools to see if you can see more information, rather than just "it doesn't load".

Comment: src will read from the same location at the html page, rather than the javascript

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using React.

Putting a video in the same folder as the source code for a React component won't expose it over HTTP. Even if it did, the resolved URL would be relative to the HTML document hosting the React application and not relative to the URL of the React component. The browser will make a request for the video, but the server won't find it.

You'd be able to tell this is you used the Developer Tools in your browser. The Network tab would show a 404 error for the video.

You need to put the video file somewhere where it will have a URL and then use that URL.

Comment: I've attempted this by uploading the file too. But this wasn't working so i tried to simplify the code to see what was going on. My original question for the full code is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57453463/my-html5-video-tag-is-not-playing-the-video/57458706#57458706. Do you have any idea why it still wasnt working when i uploaded my file? In this case my developer tools returned a 206 status code

Answer (score 0):

Your src-link should be relative to your (html) page. It does not matter, where your js-file is. So is the html file in the same folder? If yes, I would try: "./hi.mp4" as src.
otherwise use the same path, as you refer to your js file.